# Measuring the battery level powering the arduino

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, power, voltage

I would like to power my arduino nano with a 9V battery, but I would also like to measure the voltage of the battery to know its charge level.
Can I use the [MAX471 Voltage Current Sensor](https://aliexpress.com/item/32672702701.html?src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=248-630-5778&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=10191220517&albag=107473525088&trgt=743612850874&crea=fr32672702701&netw=u&device=c&albpg=743612850874&albpd=fr32672702701&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2NyFBhDoARIsAMtHtZ60kZjqZf6Pn0b21O_8pnOQl4r2uiEo-iRub2k4lLdjbPr-t_sww7MaAvAQEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) module by connecting the VIN pin to my battery and VOUT to my arduino ?

Comment: https://hackaday.io/project/25461-reading-the-max471-sensor-module, also https://github.com/wisewolf/Arduino-Power-Meter.

Comment: what kind of a 9 V battery?

Comment: If you only need to measure voltage, why not use an Arduino A/D input?  All you need to do is connect a voltage divide across the 9V terminals to divide down to the A/D range.  Use big resistors in the 100K to 1Meg range for low drain.

Comment: @Boggyman: If there are other analogRead channels active, 100k to 1M might be a bit high to load the ADC in time. An additional capacitor in parallel to the voltage divider low side might help...

Comment: @jsotola This is a 9V GF22

Comment: @Boggyman when you talk about ADC you refer to this module : ADS1015 ?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the analog inputs that are already included on the Arduino, that you can read with analogRead

Comment: @Boggyman Do you think this setup is correct? R1 = 9kΩ, R2 = 1KΩ https://ibb.co/BqGZCBS

Comment: That would work, but it's not optimal.  It would divide the 9 V battery down to 1 V, which is wasting 4/5 of the 5 V A/D range.  Also, the total resistance is only 10 K, which is a continuous drain on the battery.  I'd suggest something like R1 = R2 = 100 K to give 4.5 V and drain less current.  Depending on your overall application, you may be able to use 1 Meg as long as you are not using multiple A/D channels as @DataFiddler mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want measuring a "battery level" in mAh for example, you must measure Voltage AND Current, so INA219 is a better deal (it is a I2C control).

Comment: Are you sure that this would allow me to power my Arduino, if so is there a difference in autonomy with this module rather than the assembly of @Boggyman (less wasting) ?